# converting a list of unicode character into a Hebrew string in python

Tags: python, unicode, html-parsing

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998165/html-code-processing) thread solution, I have managed to get a bunch of lists that each looks like:

> [u'\u05ea\u05d0\u05de\u05d9\u05df \u05dc\u05d9']

I assume that those are unicode character but for some reason, I can't convert them back into Hebrew.

I tried the suggested solution in the comments in the link. I also tried to use `''.join` but it didn't work. The error I get is:

> Error Type: exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError 22:42:15 T:2806414192
>   M:2425589760   ERROR: Error Contents: 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried to wrap stuff in `unicode()` but all I got is the same as the example above.

How do I achieve that?

**Note:**
I am trying to parse [this link](http://www.mako.co.il/mako-vod-index).

**Edit:**
I am trying to convert the list into string using `join` and then print it. Here is the relevant pice of code:

```
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(link, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.XML_ENTITIES)
    programs = soup('ul')
    for i,prog in enumerate(programs):
        if i==(4+getLetterValue(name)):
            j = 0
            while j < len(prog('li')):
                li = prog('li')[j]
        link = li('a')[0]
        url = link['href']
                text = link.contents
                print ''.join(text)
```

`link` is a string. and `getLetterValue(name)` returns an integer which tells what is the position in the html document.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert them back into Hebrew."? E.g. want to write them into a utf-8 encoded file?

Comment: That already *is* a unicode string in that list, hence the `u'...`.  Please elaborate what you mean by "convert them back into Hebrew".

Comment: can you post some code for what you are trying to do? Assigning the list above to a variable and printing it gives תאמין לי which looks like hebrew to me...

Comment: For me this prints fine `[u'\u05ea\u05d0\u05de\u05d9\u05df \u05dc\u05d9']
>>> print l[0]
תאמין לי`

Comment: I want to display them on the string via xbmc.org plugin. For now, the problem is with print which, in effect, print the stuff to a file and not to the screen

Comment: Please include a code sample of how you use a different string.

Comment: That's not a code sample of how you'd use a different string to do what you want to do.  IOW, how would you normally put a string on the screen that isn't working with this string?

Comment: @Rossa Patterson: I'm not sure what you meant. The solution you wrote me doesn't work. This could be originated in the way that xbmc handles string.

Comment: "how would you normally put a string on the screen"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `unicode` string, it *is* in Hebrew and you can even print it directly on a Python interactive shell. e.g.:

```
>>> print u'\u05ea\u05d0\u05de\u05d9\u05df \u05dc\u05d9'
תאמין לי
```

*If* you really need to convert it to a raw string of bytes (a `str` object) for some reason, you have to specify the *encoding* of the byte string because text can represented in many different encodings.

Short answer: assuming you want to use UTF-8 to encode the text, you can use:

```
your_unicode_text.encode('utf-8')
```

If you are going to use a different encoding, just change the encoding name above.

For a reference on how Python deals with Unicode text and common problems, see: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/python-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-misunderstanding-encode/370199#370199) for another short explanation of Unicode and string encodings.