# Google App Engine - function which clean string from html tags

Tags: google-app-engine, tags

I have a question if there is any function which can clean a string from html tags in google app engine api?

For example I have textarea - comments and somebody wrote:

```
 <b> Bla bla bla </b>
```

I want to clean it. Is there any function to do it? or I should write my own?

I know there is cgi.escape() and the tags are ignored but they are still in this string
Thanks

Comment: Are you using python or Java in google-app-engine?

Comment: Can't you just replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`? I'm not familiar with Google App Engine, but I'd imagine the principle would be essentially the same as when coding a standard site.

Comment: @Cyclone, apparently he wants to remove html tags, not escape them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip html from strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Comment: The django part that comes with GAE has the filter: {{ value|striptags }} you also can use in your python code: defaultfilters.striptags(text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it this way

```
defaultfilters.striptags(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to rely on your templating engine to do this. Most or all templating systems include this functionality - in Django, you use the `|escape` filter - and escaping on output is far more flexible than doing it on input.