# How to eliminate html tags?

Tags: python, regex

I am getting the first paragraph from pages and trying to extract words suitable to be tags or keywords. In some paragraphs there are links and I want to remove the tags:

For instance if the text is

```
A <b>hex triplet</b> is a six-digit, three-<a href="/wiki/Byte"
enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a> ...
```

I want to remove

```
<b></b><a href="/wiki/Byte" title="Byte"></a>
```

to end up with this

```
A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte ...
```

A regex like this does not work:

```
>>> text = """A <b>hex triplet</b> is a six-digit, three-<a href="/wiki/Byte"
    enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a> ..."""
>>> f = re.findall(r'<.+>', text)
>>> f
['<b>hex triplet</b>', '</a>']
>>>
```

What is the best way to do this?

I found several similar questions but none of them I think solves this particular problem.

**Update with an example of BeautifulSoup extract (extract deletes the tag including its text and must run for each tag separately:**

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> [s.extract() for s in soup('b')]
[<b>hex triplet</b>]
>>> soup
A  is a six-digit, three-<a href="/wiki/Byte" enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a> ...
>>> [s.extract() for s in soup('a')]
[<a href="/wiki/Byte" enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a>]
>>> soup
A  is a six-digit, three- ...
>>>
```

**Update**

For people with the same question: as mentioned by Brendan Long, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python/925630#925630) using HtmlParser works best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip html from strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Comment: Also, see [Parsing Html the Cthulu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Short version: Don't do it with regular expressions.

Comment: try lxml module (see lxml.de) it is trivial using lxml

Comment: @BrendanLong: thanks for this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python it works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is greedy, meaning it will find the longest possible match. Add a `?` to force it to find the *shortest* possible match:

```
>>> re.findall(r'<.+?>', text)
['<b>', '</b>', '</a>']
```

Another way to write the regex is to explicitly exclude right angle brackets inside a tag, using `[^>]` instead of `.`.

```
>>> re.findall(r'<[^>]+>', text)
['<b>', '</b>', '<a href="/wiki/Byte"\n    enter code heretitle="Byte">', '</a>']
```

An advantage of this approach is that it will also match newlines (`\n`). You can get the same behavior with `.` if you add the [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag.

```
>>> re.findall(r'<.+?>', text, re.DOTALL)
['<b>', '</b>', '<a href="/wiki/Byte"\n    enter code heretitle="Byte">', '</a>']
```

---

To strip out the tags, use `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
'A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte ...'
```

Comment: but this does not catch `<a href="/wiki/Byte" title="Byte">``. Is there a way to include that too?

Comment: Ok, thanks, your edit works now. How do I remove the matches from the string? I don't see a method for this in the documentation.

Comment: Strings are immutable; you can re-assign it though.

Answer (score 3):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is the answer to your problem! Try it out, it's pretty awesome!

Html parsing would become so easy once you use it.

```
>>> text = """A <b>hex triplet</b> is a six-digit, three-<a href="/wiki/Byte"
... enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a> ..."""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
u'A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte ...'
```

If you have all your text that you want to extract enclosed in some outer tags like `<body> ... </body>` or some `<div id="X"> .... </div>`, then you can do the following (this illustration assumes that all the text you want to extract is enclosed within the `<body>` tag). Now you can selectively extract text from only some desired tags.

(Look at the documentation and examples and you will find many ways of parsing the DOM)

```
>>> text = """<body>A <b>hex triplet</b> is a six-digit, 
... three-<a href="/wiki/Byte"
... enter code heretitle="Byte">byte</a>
... </body>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> ''.join(soup.body.findAll(text=True))
u'A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte'
```

Comment: I added an example with Beautiful Soup using `extract`. But extract removes the tag including its text content and also I need to run `extract` for each tag in html. Is there a better way to do this with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: @Zeynel Did the solution help?

Comment: Yes, this was helpful but I decided to use the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python in this case. Thanks again.

Comment: I am back to trying this solution but in my case the text is not enclosed in <body> tags or <div> tags. I am getting the first paragraph of a page with js like this: `var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];` Is there a way to make your answer work when text is not part of DOM? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just the basic elements to strip tags. Including missing elements,
the \w's below represent qualified unicode tag names with prefix and body,
that need a join() statement to form the subexpression. The virtue of parsing
html/xml with regex is it won't fail on the first ill-formed instance, which
makes it perfect for fixing it! The vice is that its slow as sh*t, especially
with unicode.

Unfortunately, stripping tags destroys content since by definition, markup
*formats* content.

Try this on a big web page. This should be translatable into python.

```
$rx_expanded = '
<
(?:
    (?:
       (?:
           (?:script|style) \s*
         | (?:script|style) \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*
       )> .*? </(?:script|style)\s*
    )
  |
    (?:
        /?\w+\s*/?
      | \w+\s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?
      | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
    )
)
>
';

$html =~ s/$rx_expanded/[was]/xsg;
```