# python regular expression replace

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to change a string that contains substrings such as

```
the</span></p>
<p><span class=font7>currency
```

to

```
the currency
```

At the line break is CRLF

The words before and after the code change. I only want to replace if the second word starts with a lower case letter. The only thing that changes in the code is the digit after 'font'

I tried:

```
p = re.compile('</span></p>\r\n<p><span class=font\d>([a-z])')
res = p.sub(' \1', data)
```

but this isn't working

How should I fix this?

Comment: because regex shouldn't be used to parse html.

Comment: In addition to @JBernardo your question is unclear. Such as? So what else?

Comment: @FailedDev: does the edit clarify?

Comment: @JBernardo: what would you suggest, especially to replace only if the second word starts with a lower case letter?

Comment: How about putting `python strip html` into the search box and pressing enter? The first hit will get you [this nifty anser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python/925630#925630).

Comment: Why is it not working? What result do you get?

Comment: @ekhumoro: because the string is littered with other html that I don't want to strip

Comment: @heltonbiker: the compile statement is not matching anything in the string.  The string has many occurrences of substrings in the form indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead assertion.

```
p = re.compile('</span></p>\r\n<p><span class=font\d>(?=[a-z])')
res = p.sub(' ', data)
```

Comment: That does not seem to find the substring. p.match(data) returns nothing

Comment: @foosion: `match` searches from the start of the string.  Try `p.search(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
result = re.sub("(?si)(.*?)</?[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[^>]*>.*</?[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[^>]*>(.*)", r"\1 \2", subject)
```

Applied to :

```
the</span></p>
<p><span class=font7>currency
```

Produces :

```
the currency
```

Although I would strongly suggest against using regex with xml/html/xhtml. THis generic regex will remove all elements and capture any text before / after to groups 1,2.

Comment: The reason the html seems reversed is that you're seeing the end of one paragraph and the beginning of another.  That regex seems very complex

Comment: @foosion Well this regex will work regardless of any elements you throw in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the flag re.DOTALL, which means it will "see" nonprintable characters, such as linebreaks, as if they were regular characters.

So, first line of your code would become :

```
p = re.compile('</span></p>..<p><span class=font\d>([a-z])', re.DOTALL)
```

(not the two unescaped dots instead of the linebreak).

Actually, there is also re.MULTILINE, everytime I have a problem like this one of those end up solving the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That does not seem to find the substring.  p.match(data) returns nothing.