# Remove the Html tags in regex

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip html from strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have the regex pattern in my python module which removes the html tags from the given string.

It doesn't work for this case.

Input string:

```
string=<li class="
      tal
    "><h3><a href="/aclk?sa=l&amp;ai=CoS4y-Wz0TrnqC8y0rAfysK2DB46PiJECzoK8_yKPwd4FCAAQAigCUL7Kz4P9_____wFg5erjg5gOoAH0m_XuA8gBAakCoqvilYNWVD6qBB1P0Dm6CNzrf62IC36fDvUIh77EpeheIRdH_YEaPw&amp;sig=AOD64_2z9xPK8vOxUCpIGTjBcc2Lg-GAeA&amp;adurl=http://www.policybazaar.com/creditcards/creditcard-india.aspx%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dppc%26utm_term%3DCreditcard_delhi_only%26utm_campaign%3Dcredit_card" id="pa2">Compare <b>Credit Cards</b> | PolicyBazaar.com</a></h3>Get Best <b>Credit Card</b> For Free, Now U Have a Choice, Choose wisely!<br /><cite>www.policybazaar.com/<b>credit</b>-<b>Cards</b></cite></li>
```

regex pattern:

```
 In [64]:p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
 In [65]:text=p.sub('',str(string))
 In [66]: text
 Out[66]: '<li class="\n          tal\n        ">Compare Credit Cards | PolicyBazaar.comGet Best Credit Card For Free, Now U Have a Choice, Choose wisely!www.policybazaar.com/credit-Cards'
```

The result has the `<li>` tag still.  How it should be removed irrespective of this class name and string pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you should use the `DOTALL` functionality:

```
p = re.compile(r'<.*?>',re.DOTALL)
```

should work.

But... you should not use regexes for HTML parsing, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11621

HTH.

Comment: +1 But instead of the `.*?` lazy-dot-star, a faster and more accurate expression would be: `p = re.compile(r'<[^>]*>')`, or better yet: `p = re.compile(r"""<(?:[^<>"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>""")`, which allows attributes with angle brackets. But as others point out, all these regexes can still fail. Better to parse the HTML with a tool designed for the job (as Zsolt Botykai correctly points out in this answer).

Comment: @ridgerunner TIL about angle brackets are allowed in attributes, wow :-) And yeah you are right, your regexes are more accurate. Mine only should work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Google or search Stackoverflow for HTML and regex - this is a bad idea.  You'd be better off using Beautiful Soup or some other real HTML parser and modifying the DOM.

Comment: I use Beautiful Soup for HTML parsing. Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to remove all of the HTML from the string, you might look into this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440481-strips-xmlhtml-tags-from-string/