# Using HTMLParser in Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing, arguments, web-scraping, stripping

I have been using HTML Parser to scrapping data from websites and stripping html coding whilst doing so. I'm aware of various modules such as Beautiful Soup, but decided to go down the path of not depending on "outside" modules. There is a code code supplied by Eloff: [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925630/3416774)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

It works in Python 3.1. However, I recently upgraded to Python 3.2.x and have found I get errors regarding the HTML Parser code as written above.

My first error points to the line:

```
s.feed(html)
```

... and the error says ...

```
AttributeError: 'MLStripper' object has no attribute 'strict'
```

So, after a bit of research, I add "strict=True" to the top line, making it...

```
class MLStripper(HTMLParser, strict=True)
```

However, I get the new error of:

```
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

To see what would happen, I removed the "self" argument and left in the "strict=True"... which gave up the error:

```
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

... and I got the "I'm guessing on guesses" feeling.

I have no idea what the third argument in the `class MLStripper(HTMLParser)` line would be, after `self` and `strict=True`; research didn't toss any enlightenment.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're subclassing `HTMLParser`, but you aren't calling its `__init__` method. You need to add one line to your `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.reset()
    self.fed = []
```

Also, for Python 3, the import line is:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

With these changes, a simple example works. Don't change the `class` line, that's not related.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thomas K. Thank you very much! Scripts are working perfectly once again with that "super().__init__()" code inserted.

Comment: This also resolves the 
AttributeError: 'HTMLTagRemover' object has no attribute 'convert_charrefs'

super().__init__() was NOT required in Python2 for me but was in Python3 - thanks

Comment: I would change last line of the get_data function to be return ' '.join(self.fed) with a space rather than an empty string.  Otherwise <p>Foo</p><p>Bar</p> turns into "FooBar" rather than "Foo Bar".  This turns out to be a pretty common case in HTML in the wild.