# How to remove texts within html tags in python?

Tags: python, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip html from strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

While making a small browser like application, I am facing the problem of spliting the different tags. Consider the string

```
<html> <h1> good morning </h1> welcome </html>
```

I need the following output:
   ['good morning','welcome']

How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of pythons html / xml parsers.

Beautiful soup is popular. lmxl is popular too.

The above are third party pacakges you could use standard library too

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 3):

I would use `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
def get_text(etree):
    for child in etree:
        if child.text:
           yield child.text
        if child.tail:
           yield child.tail

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<html> <h1> good morning </h1> welcome </html>')
print list(get_text(root))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the python library [`Beautiful Soup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to achieve your goal. It's just a couple of lines with its help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html> <h1> good morning </h1> welcome </html>')
print [text for text in soup.stripped_strings]
```