# Is there something like NLTK that comes with python, and that does not have to be installed?

Tags: python

I'm using NLTK to strip tags and leave text in an html file.

NLTK installs in seconds on my linux computer, but on Windows it's a pain to use, and I know that my client who lives in a different country will not be able to install the nltk module if I'm having trouble doing it.

What is a SIMPLE alternative that ships with python and that doesn't need to be installed?
I need this as part of a script.

Comment: why would you want to use NLTK (natural language processing TK) for parsing html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip html from strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Was the question "How to remove HTML tags from a string?"

```
import re
def strip_tags(s):
    return re.sub("<[^>]+>", "", s)
```

Also, for future reference, you'll just want [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extensions for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)  page.

EDIT: Fixed the regexp. D:

Double edit: inspired by the comments, here's an abomination.

```
def strip_tags(s):
     return re.sub(r"""</?\w+(\s*([^=]+=(?P<q>['"]).+?(?P=q))|\s*\w+(=\w+)?)*>""", "", s)
```

Comment: `strip_tags("<p>This doesn't work</p>")`  We can play this game all day -- HTML isn't a regular language,  and so you [shouldn't parse it with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)..

Comment: Crap, typo in the original regexp, @DSM.

Comment: Either way the revised regexp _will_ strip tags, leaving only the plain-text content. Not sure if that's what OP wanted, but.

Comment: AKX: okay, you want to play?  Let's play. :^)  `"""<p><img src="pic.png" alt="Try harder! :>"> Your revision doesn't work either. </p>"""`.

Comment: Heh - yeah, I knew that'd come up. The above `strip_tags` works for the majority of HTML one might see in the wild, but you're right, not everything.

Comment: I can't object too strongly -- I've done similar things myself when I just wanted stuff to work quickly -- but inevitably on larger data samples I wind up with something that wasn't escaped that should have been, or a missing tag somewhere that breaks everything. :-/

Comment: @DSM: I added a terrible thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parser('whatever')
text = filter(None, ((el.text or '').strip() for el in root.findall('.//*')))
```

Then what you do with `text` is up to you.