# How can I convert HTML into text without markup in Python?

Tags: python, html

I need to get plain text from an HTML document while honoring `<br>` elements as newlines. `BeautifulSoup.text` does not process `<br>` and newlines. HTML2Text is quite nice, but it converts to markdown. How else could I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use the following method. You can do a manual `.replace('<br>','\r\n')` on the string before passing it to `strip_tags(html)` to honor new lines.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out tags and replace them with spaces (if needed):

```
import re

myString = re.sub(r"<(/)?br(/)?>", "\n", myString)
myString = re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", " ", myString)
```