# Remove HTML tags from output

Tags: python, html, scrape

I'm new to python and am having trouble removing html tags from the output. I'd like to remove the a tags and the content within them. I'd like to also remove the p tags. Any suggestions?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Ask user to enter URL
url = raw_input("Please enter a valid URL: ")

# Make sure file is clear for new content
open('ctp_output.txt', 'w').close()

# Open txt document for output
txt = open('ctp_output.txt', 'w')

# Parse HTML of article, aka making soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# retrieve all of the paragraph tags
tags = soup('p')
txt.write(str(tag) + '\n' + '\n')

# Close txt file with new content added
txt.close()
```

Comment: This might be useful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the text part from a tag by using the `get_text()` function instead of the string representation (`str(tag)`).

In the code above the change would be to replace this line:

```
txt.write(str(tag) + '\n' + '\n')
```

with:

```
txt.write(tag.get_text() + '\n' + '\n')
```

Comment: I had to put it into a for loop to overcome the ResultSet instance issue. But it's working very well. Thanks for the help! I'd upvote you if I could.

Comment: Good that you got it to work! If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark the answer as accepted (no need to upvote).