# Remove HTML Tags from Python List

Tags: python, html, parsing, append

I have a python list of three values:

```
address = 
[<p>
<strong>CVS Pharmacy #</strong><br/>
                        1025 St Clair River Dr <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-794-4941
                        </p>,
<p>
<strong>Kroger Pharmacy</strong><br/>
                        2600 Pointe Tremble <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-671-4002
                        </p>,
<p>
<strong>Rite Aid Pharmacy 04943</strong><br/>
                        402 Pointe Tremble Road <br/>
                        Algonac, MI 48001<br/>
                        1-810-794-4985
                        </p>]
```

And I want to remove the HTML tags.  When try to do so one by one:

```
print(address[0].text)
```

I get:

```
    CVS Pharmacy #
                        1025 St Clair River Dr 
                        Algonac, MI 48001
                        1-810-794-4941
```

which is what I want.  However, when I iterate through a loop, I get:

```
[u'\nCVS Pharmacy #\n                            1025 St Clair River Dr \n                                 Algonac, MI 48001\n                            1-810-794-4941\n                            ', u'\nKroger Pharmacy\n                            2600 Pointe Tremble \n                            Algonac, MI 48001\n                            1-810-671-4002\n                            ', u'\nRite Aid Pharmacy 04943\n                            402 Pointe Tremble Road \n                            Algonac, MI 48001\n                            1-810-794-4985\n                            ']
```

which is not what I want, since it has all the u's and \n's and other garbage, and it's all in one long string.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I also want to eventually append these to an already existing csv file, if there is an easy way to kill two birds with one stone.

Thanks.

Comment: `u` is unicode. "\n" is newline so it is not garbage, are you going to write it all on one line in your csv file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from strings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`u` means its unicode string. `\n` are new line characters. You can write a regex to remove new line characters, multiple spaces, tabs etc to single space.

```
import re

CLEAN = re.compile('\s+')

address = [CLEAN.sub(' ', a.text).strip() for a in address]
```

Or perhaps replace new line with comma so that address formatting make sense.

```
address = [CLEAN.sub(' ', a.text.replace('\n', ',')).strip() for a in address]
```

Comment: \s will not remove new lines. Regex is good solution but then you need specifically put \n in your re.compile. I also don't see the point in replacing new line with a space.

Comment: @Everst `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. It do removes new lines.

Comment: Yes, my bad, when UNICODE flag is not specified it is equivalent to that regex set.