# Removing html tags from a website using python code

Tags: python, html

I would like to know how to remove HTML tags from a given website using python. I want to be able to output all the text within a html page excluding all the HTML code

Comment: Perhaps if you explain exactly what you're trying to do we can suggest a more logical approach. What you are describing sounds to me like you're trying to do extract a specific piece of information and not just "output all the text".

Comment: stripped_text = re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', html_text)

Comment: I'm want to strip all the html code from the contents of a website leaving only the text e.g content = "<HTML> <p>Hello world <\p>  <\html>  I want to be able to Remove all the HTML code and then output the text in this case "Hello world"

Comment: the following might be a help: [Here][1]
and do not use RE... bad idea

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Then you can get all stripped text by simply:

```
soup.get_text()
```