# Delete HTML Tags from string Python

Tags: python, html, tags, feedparser

I'm developing a script using feedparser (to extract RSS Feeds).
Using some functions I end up having a string named description like this:

```
"This is the description of the feed. < img alt='' height='1' src='http://linkOfARandomImage.of/the/feed' width='1' />"
```

The html tags can vary, i can have img, a href, "p", "h1",... and the ammount may also vary. So they are quite random. But what I want to do is only keep the first text.
I'd like to know if there is a way to delete everything which are tags, I was thinking on doing something like: from this character "<" to the end, delete everything. But it's possible that there is a "<" in the middle of the description.
Hope you get what I'm trying to do.
Thanks

Comment: Might it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all tags:

```
import re
text = "This is the description of <img alt='' height='1' src='http://linkOfARandomImage.of/the/feed' width='1' /> the <br> text"
text = re.sub("<.*?>", "", text)
#text = "This is the description of  the  text"
```

Delete unnecessary whitespaces:

```
text = re.sub("\w*", " ", text)
```

EDIT:

```
text = re.sub("\w+", " ", text)
```

Comment: Correct, but note that it is usually not a good practice to parse HTML with regex. There are parsers for that. This is not to invalidate your answer, just to point the OP's attention on the fact that it may not be extrapolated as "how do I parse HTML? With regex!"

Comment: Yeh, `\w*` matches zero or more word characters.

Comment: Jivan, this is not exactly a html file, it's a RSS, I used FeedParser to scrap it but the functions given don't do exactly what I wanted so I needed to change it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **delete the first text (before any tag appears)**, no need to bother with a regex.

Simply use `split` and `strip`.

```
>>> html = "Some text here <tag>blabla</tag> <other>hey you</other>"
>>> text = html.split("<")[0].strip()
>>> text
"Some text here"
```

`split` cuts the `html` string when it encounters the specified character.

`strip` removes all white spaces at the beginning and at the end of the resulting string.

**Caveat**: this only works if you don't have any `<` in the text you want to keep.