# python remove html tags including html entities but not normal text with a '&' prefix

Tags: python, html

I want to remove html tags including html entities such as `&amp;` in python 2.7, but my input text contains normal text that starts with a letter `&`, I don't want to remove such text. I am trying the most voted answer in this post: [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925630/2728388). The only difference is, I am replacing html tags with a `space`.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ' '.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

print strip_tags('html tags<p>will be&amp;replaced</p>with space. NOT this &abc')
# Now the output is:  "html tags will be replaced with space. NOT this  "
# The wanted output is:  "html tags will be replaced with space. NOT this &abc"
```

How can I output the correct text?

Comment: Well the & character is a special character in html so &abc should really be &amp;abc the parser is behaving correctly.

Comment: & can also appear in a URL. If my input text has URL, then the upper code will make the URL invalid. @e4c5

Comment: Your question said input text nothing about urls. In the case of & characters in the href tag they will be handled correctly by html parser libraries

Comment: What if the URL is not embedded in between two html tags, it appears as a single piece of text. But the URL contains & character. How to make sure this & character being handled correctly? @e4c5

Comment: What is to be done with valid entity references? Your latest example shows it being replaced by a space.... is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, @mhawke, I want valid entity references being replaced by space, not those common & characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> html = '<div><p>&abc is <b>my</b> input text</p></div>'
>>> print strip_tags(html)
 is  my  input text

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.text
&abc is my input text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('=&abc= is my input text')
>>> soup.text
u'=&abc= is my input text'
```

Notice that your `strip_tags()` does not properly strip the nested `<b>` tag that I added to your test string.

If you want to persist with using the standard HTMLParser, there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703994/21945) to the question that you link to that does a better job. For my test string it will output `&abc; is my input text`, i.e. it will escape the standalone `&`. I am not sure which output you are after.

**Update**

This works:

```
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from htmlentitydefs import entitydefs

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
        self.entityref = re.compile('&[a-zA-Z][-.a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9]')

    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.fed.append(' ')

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.fed.append(' ')

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        if entitydefs.get(name) is None:
            m = self.entityref.match(self.rawdata.splitlines()[self.lineno-1][self.offset:])
            entity = m.group()
            # semicolon is consumed, other chars are not.
            if entity[-1] != ';':
                entity = entity[:-1]
            self.fed.append(entity)
        else:
            self.fed.append(' ')

    def get_data(self):
        self.close()    # N.B. ensure all buffered data has been processed
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

print strip_tags('html &zzz; tags<p>&zzz &zz: will be&amp;replaced</p>with space. NOT this &abc')
```

**Output**

```
html &zzz; tags &zzz &zz: will be replaced with space. NOT this &abc
```

This code adds handlers for start and end tags which are replaced by a single space. Entity references are also handled by replacing known valid references with a space, and leaving unknown ones unchanged.

One other important issue is to call `close()` on the parser before you call `get_data()`. I put it in the `get_data()` method, although you could instead add it to the `strip_tags()` function. I don't think that it matters if `close()` is called multiple times, so you can call `get_data()` and then feed more data to the parser.

Comment: That answer replaces html tags with null. I want to replace html tags but not &abc with space, so I change it to ' '.join(). Could you help?

Comment: I got &abc; is my input text using your code. There is a semicolon which is unwanted.

Comment: @DehengYe: if you mean that you used the BeautifulSoup example, it produces exactly the output that you show in your question. I have updated the answer to show that. There is no semicolon. Could you show a clear example of what you want when HTML tags are added to the string? Should start tags, end tags, or both be replaced with a space?

Comment: Thank @mhawke . The question description is updated.

Comment: @DehengYe: I have updated my answer with a working `HTMLParser` solution.

Comment: This edited answer solves my problem @mhawke. I could say nothing but appreciations, appreciations and appreciations.

Comment: @DehengYe: I have updated again with an issue that I just noticed. Not sure if that will be a problem for you.

Comment: I see your newest edits. @mhawke. Is there a way to keep that &zzz; as it is?

Comment: @DehengYe: I have updated the entity processing code to access the raw data and grab the entity reference directly from there. It's a bit of a hack, and it might not work on data with `\r` line terminators; it should work for `\n` and \`r\n` though.

Comment: if I do strip_tags('&a') using your code, it gives error. @mhawke

Comment: Yes, HTMLParser raises an exception because it sees an entity ref but the file/string ends before the entity is complete. There's not much that can be done about that.... anyway, you are asking a lot of HTMLParser to handle this, after all, it is not valid HTML to have unescaped `&` characters in the input. Your input should be `&amp;a`.