# request.args.get returns none for ajax request

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to implement in place editing in html5. Trying to implement this

http://w3lessons.info/2014/04/13/html5-inline-edit-with-php-mysql-jquery-ajax/

But in flask,ajax and jquery instead.
When I send ajax request to flask app, it cannot seems to access data i pass for "dd" tag. This is the route function I have

```
@app.route('/updateNode', methods=['POST'])
def updateNode():
 fieldToEdit = request.args.get('fieldToEdit', None)
 value = request.args.get('value', None)

 app.logger.debug(value)
 app.logger.debug(fieldToEdit)
 if value == None:
    return jsonify(success=0)
 else:
    return jsonify(success=1)
```

Always see None when I check using app.logger.debug(value)

DEBUG in view: None

DEBUG in view: None

My Ajax code is something like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("dd[contenteditable=true]").blur(function()
  {
    var field_user = $(this).attr("id") ;
    var value = $(this).html() ;
    console.log(field_user);
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/updateNode",
      data: {
        'fieldToEdit' : field_user,
        'value': value
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(rsp){
        console.log("Ajax call was successful" + rsp);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log('request failed ' + e);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I can see right value in developer tool console before making ajax call.

My Html code

```
<li>
  <dl>
   <dt>Age</dt>
   <dd id="editAge"contenteditable="true">40</dd>
  </dl>
</li>
```

Sample code in runnable
http://code.runnable.com/me/VqbxNjRjLVNkRnxN

.html() should only return value, so I cannot understand why request.args.get cannot retrieve value from key value pair supplied in data

Comment: what does `console.log(value)` print

Answer (score 0):

For these purposes, I am not sure you want to send the actual HTML of the value, as it will have HTML tags.

The docs.

html ():
http://api.jquery.com/html/

> In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any
>   element. If the selector expression matches more than one element,
>   only the first match will have its HTML content returned. Consider
>   this code:

```
$( "div.demo-container" ).html();
```

> In order for the following 's content to be retrieved, it would
>   have to be the first one with class="demo-container" in the document:

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
```

> The result would look like this:

```
<div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
```

As you can see however, the HTML tags are still there.

You should use `text()`

The docs
http://api.jquery.com/text/

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
>   documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
>   combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
>   parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
>   and other white space.) Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list <strong>item</strong> 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code `$( "div.demo-container" ).text()` would produce the following result:

> Demonstration Box list item 1 list item 2

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. In Flask route function it is still "None". console.log(value) print the right values from <dd id="editAge"contenteditable="true">40</dd> i.e 40. I thought it was something to do with html tags, so I tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python, but then I get this error - TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly.

Comment: try .innerHTML? (not a function)

Comment: There is no .innerHTML in jquery. According to doc link- html (): http://api.jquery.com/html/ .html() function uses the browser's innerHTML property

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve it using this code instead

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
 $(function() {
  $('dd[contenteditable=true]').bind('blur', function() {
    $.getJSON('/updateNode', {
      a: $(this).attr("id"),
      b: $(this).text()
    }, function(data) {
    console.log("Ajax call was successful" + data);
   });
   return false;
  });
 });
</script>
```

But, I don't know why it didn't work with $.ajax method