# Get json payload then strip the html with python

Tags: python, json, parsing, strip

I have a json values that I need stripped of all html tags.

**After using the following function:**

```
def payloaded():
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("www.example.com/payload.json") as r:
    data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
text = (data["body"]["und"][0]["value"])
return(text)
```

**This is the returned (text):**

```
&lt;div class=&quot;blah&quot;&gt;'<p>This is the text.</p>\r\n'
```

**This is the original (text):**

```
<div class="blah"><p>This is the text.</p>
```

Note: I need all html tags stripped, and there is no real guidelines of what the tags I will be getting.

**This is what I want the (text) to be:**

```
This is the text.
```

**This is the post function I am using:**

```
def add_node_basic(text)
url = "www.example.com"
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
payload = {
    "auth_token": x,
    "docs":
        {
            "id": y,
            "fields": [
                {"name": "body", "value": text, "type": "text"},
            ]}
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the input json file?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you are looking for @PaulRooney `def add_node_basic(text)
    url = "www.example.com"
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "auth_token": x,
        "docs":
            {
                "id": y,
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "body", "value": text, "type": "text"},
                ]}
    }
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)`                   You may be looking for this: The original text `<div class="blah"><p>This is the text.</p>...`

Comment: I went ahead and added it to the main section. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *slicing* the string along with `find` method, like this:

```
>>> print text[text.find('<p>'):text.find('</p>')].strip('<p>')
This is the text.
```

If you are trying to extract text only from the HTML source, then you can use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) library in Python. Example:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are various other "tags" that are not similar throughout the 1000+ pages I will be running this through. I would need a way to strip all html leaving me with only the good text. This seems like it might work for some one off use cases though.

Comment: In that case, your question is a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python). {Hint: Use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)} Updated it in my answer as well.