# How can I str.replace() <br> or '=' in Python?

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time trying to get rid of all the extra HTML tags within the text I scraped from a certain web page, however, `str.replace()` in Python doesn't seem to be working for targets like `<br>` and `=`, while other tags such as `<li></li>` will be successfully replaced.

Here's my code.

```
str(txt).replace('<li>', '')
        .replace('</li>', '')
        .replace('<ol>', '')
        .replace('</ol>', '')
        .replace('<br>', '')
        .replace('=', '')
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from strings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get the text from the page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
text = soup.get_text()
```

`BeautifulSoup` parses the html, and has an easy built-in function for getting the text.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll give it a try!