# How to remove all occurrences of sub strings between two tags from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of substrings between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` in the below string and also remove `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>`:

```
txt = '<p>Large pythons were <pre><code> the subject of many </code></pre> a news story </p>\n last year due to the fact that there were at least two deaths <pre><code> directly attributable to them </code></pre>. Tragically, the deaths would not have happened had <pre><code> the owners of these snakes kept them </code></pre> safely, and responsibly, contained. The following article, by David Chiszar, Hobart M. Smith, <a href= Albert Petkus and Joseph Dougherty </a>, was recently published in the Bulletin of the Chicago Herpetological Society, and represents the first clear, and accurate, <p> account of the death that occurred July 1993</p>\n'
```

I wrote the following code to remove these tags for three occurrences of substrings.

```
def remsubstr( s, first, last ):
if first and last not in s:
    return s

try:
    start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
    end = s.index( last, start )
    d = (s[:start] +" "+ s[end:]).replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>\n', '')
    started = d.index("<pre><code>" )
    ended = d.index("</code></pre>") + len("</code></pre>")
    nw = d.replace(d[started:ended], '')

    if first and last in nw:
        start = nw.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = nw.index( last, start )
        d1 = (nw[:start] +" "+ nw[end:])
        started = d1.index("<pre><code>" )
        ended = d1.index("</code></pre>") + len("</code></pre>")
        nw1 = d1.replace(d1[started:ended], '')

        if first and last in nw1:
            start = nw1.index( first ) + len( first )
            end = nw1.index( last, start )
            d2 = (nw1[:start] +" "+ nw1[end:])
            started = d2.index("<pre><code>" )
            ended = d2.index("</code></pre>") + len("</code></pre>")
            nw2 = d2.replace(d2[started:ended], '')
            return nw2

        return nw1

    return nw

except ValueError:
    return ""
```

I'm able to remove all the required tags using the above code for the example:

```
remsubstr(txt,"<pre><code>", "</code></pre>")
```

Result:

```
'Large pythons were  a news story  last year due to the fact that there were at least two deaths . Tragically, the deaths would not have happened had  safely, and responsibly, contained. The following article, by David Chiszar, Hobart M. Smith, <a href= Albert Petkus and Joseph Dougherty </a>, was recently published in the Bulletin of the Chicago Herpetological Society, and represents the first clear, and accurate,  account of the death that occurred July 1993'
```

I have thousands of strings for which the function should be applied to remove multiple occurrences of this scenario.

Looking for help to write code which removes all the substrings between the tags and that works for more than three instances of the substrings/tags.

Comment: Never use regular expressions for HTML. Use a HTML parser. There are several options for Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Comment: In fact the intended operation (remove a bunch of black-listed elements) is absolutely trivial with an HTML parser. Much easier than any string operation would ever be. Look around, this question has not been asked for the first time. Disregard all solutions that recommend string replace or regex and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). There you can combine .find_all() and .decompose(). In your case, this should do it:

```
import bs4

txt = '<p>Large pythons were <pre><code> the subject of many </code></pre> a news story </p>\n last year due to the fact that there were at least two deaths <pre><code> directly attributable to them </code></pre>. Tragically, the deaths would not have happened had <pre><code> the owners of these snakes kept them </code></pre> safely, and responsibly, contained. The following article, by David Chiszar, Hobart M. Smith, <a href= Albert Petkus and Joseph Dougherty </a>, was recently published in the Bulletin of the Chicago Herpetological Society, and represents the first clear, and accurate, <p> account of the death that occurred July 1993</p>\n'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all('pre'):
    if tag.find('code'):
        tag.decompose()

result = str(soup)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), standard string operations are not optimal for the nesting found in XML files.