# Is there any other way to extract data from dynamic website, rather than using selenium?

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the data from the website https://shop.nordstrom.com/ for all the products (like shirt, t-shirt and so on). The page is dynamically loaded. I know I can use selenium with headless browser, but that is also a time consuming process and looking up on the elements, having strange ID and class names, that is also not so promising.

So I thought of looking up on the Network tool, if I can find the path to the API, from where the data is being loaded (XHR Request) . But I could not find any thing helpful. So is there a way to get the data from the website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `selenium` then the alternative is to use a web parser like `bs4` or use simply the `request` module.

You are on the right path in finding the call to the `API`. `XHR` requests can be seen under the `network` tab but the multitude of resources that appears makes it intricate to understand the requests being made. A simple way around this is to use the following method:

> Instead of `Network` tab go to the `console` tab. There click on the `settings` icon, and then tick just the option `Log XMLHTTPRequests`.

Now refresh the page and scroll down to initiate dynamic calls. You will now be able to see the logs of all `XHR` in a more clear way.

For example

> (index):29 Fetch finished loading: GET "**[https://shop.nordstrom.com/api/recs?page_type=home&placement=HP_SALE%2CHP_TOP_RECS%2CHP_CUST_HIS%2CHP_AFF_BRAND%2CHP_FTR&channel=web&bound=24%2C24%2C24%2C24%2C6&apikey=9df15975b8cb98f775942f3b0d614157&session_id=0&shopper_id=df0fdb2bb2cf4965a344452cb42ce560&country_code=US&experiment_id=945b2363-c75d-4950-b255-194803a3ee2a&category_id=2375500&style_id=0%2C0%2C0%2C0&ts=1593768329863&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.nordstrom.com%2F&zip_code=null**"](https://shop.nordstrom.com/api/recs?page_type=home&placement=HP_SALE%2CHP_TOP_RECS%2CHP_CUST_HIS%2CHP_AFF_BRAND%2CHP_FTR&channel=web&bound=24%2C24%2C24%2C24%2C6&apikey=9df15975b8cb98f775942f3b0d614157&session_id=0&shopper_id=df0fdb2bb2cf4965a344452cb42ce560&country_code=US&experiment_id=945b2363-c75d-4950-b255-194803a3ee2a&category_id=2375500&style_id=0%2C0%2C0%2C0&ts=1593768329863&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.nordstrom.com%2F&zip_code=null**%22).

Making a get request to that `URL` gives a bunch of `Json` objects. You can now use this `url` and others that you can derive to make the request straight to the `URL`.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414216/issues-with-web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-on-dynamic-html-websites) on how you can integrate the `url` with a request module to fetch data.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply. Yes your solution really helped me a lot (actually the API path you provided.). But I still have a problem.  I could not find the API Path (that you provided) in the console tab. I really don't know why ? Also, actually I was looking up for a specific product (e.g t-shirt). I want that data to be returned in JSON format (it's API path). But I cannot find the path. If you could please find the API path to the search query, t-shirt, it would really be helpful.

Comment: EDIT: Actually I tried using the VPN, and was able to get the desired results I wanted. Also Thank you @AzyCrw4282. You really helped me solve the problem.