# Scrapy - Cleaning up text[/p] from nested links[/a] etc

Tags: scrapy, scrape

I am new to python and scrape as well. Nevertheless, I spend a few days trying to scrape news articles from its archive - SUCCESSFULLY.

PROBLEM is that when I scrape CONTENT of the article `<p>` that content is filled with additional tags like - `strong`, `a` etc. And as such scrapy won't pull it out and  I am left with news article containing 2/3 of the text. Will try HTML below:

```
<p> According to <a> Japan's newspapers </a> it happened ... </p>
```

Now I tried googling around and looking into the forum here. There were some suggestion but from what I tried, it did not work or broke my spider:

[image]

I have read about normalized-space and remove tags but it didn't work. Thank you for any insights in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post your code as an image. It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide your selector for more detailed help.

Given what you're describing, I'd guess you're selecting `p/text()` (xml) or `p::text` (css), which is not going to get the text in the children of `<p>` elements.

You should try selecting `response.xpath('//p/descendant-or-self::*/text()')` to get the text in the `<p>` and all it's children.

You could also just select the `<p>`, not its text, and you'll get its children as well. From there you can start cleaning up the tags. There are [answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python) regarding how to do that.

Comment: Going to read it. Tried the suggested solution above, atm trying to google how to implement it. The selector for the content is:  item['content'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="postBody"]/p/text()').extract()

Comment: Yes please see my edit about how to select text of descendant or self. I believe that will fix you up.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Just one question if I may, can I apply the same thing into other selectors [items]. Same things happen in case the website has a link on the author os prominent date ...?

Comment: You should be able to apply this selector pattern wherever you like, as long as the path is valid you'll get what's there.

Comment: Also, another thing how to fix that problem in scrapy - when I have /text() I can just write //text() and it apparently does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.replace(,)

```
new_string = old_string.replace("<a>", "")
```

You could integrate this into a loop which iterates over a list that contains all of the substrings that you want to discard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end, it seems that Pwinz solved it. Nevertheless thanks for your effort :)