# Regex find all p tags inside quotes without other text

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

I'm trying to edit a poorly translated book.

I have text with lots of unnecessary p tags in it. I want to find all p tags inside quotes as in this piece : 
`“…Hmm. </p>Is… That, really so…?”` and to remove those p tags. 
I managed to come up with a regex to find such sentences (`\“.*</p>.*\”`), but I can't imagine one to select only `</p>` inside quotes without other text so that I can just replace them all in a single click. Send help please.

edit1: changed all words "brackets" to "quotes".

Comment: ‘Inside brackets’, your examples seem to indicate you mean “inside double quotes”?

Comment: Yes, I mean "inside quotes". My bad.

Comment: This is trickier than it might appear. You are removing the  end </p> tag but if you don’t remove the corresponding start <p> tag you will end up with invalid HTML. Sometimes that doesn’t matter but it may mess with the formatting.

Comment: You can probably use lookaheads and lookbehinds to do this in one step, but I would probably just do it in two steps. First find the quotes then remove the p’s as a second step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(?<=\“(.|\n)*)(<\/p>)(?=(.|\n)*\”)
```

Comment: It works as I wanted, but can you make it also multiline? (There are some places that are left unedited)