# how to use python to iterate through a column with html text, remove the tags, and append clean text in a new column?

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe that has a column(s) with text that includes html tags. I would like to strip out all the html tags and leave just the clean text, which I want to append into a new columns. So far I was able to clean the text using the following code but I want do this for all rows and for multiple columns that include html tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import unescape
soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(html_text), 'lxml')
text = soup.get_text(separator=' ')
print(text)
```

Here is what my data table looks like:
[image]

This is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python answer your question?

Comment: I can strip the the tags using the code above but I need to use that code and iterate through every row and create a new column with the clean text.

Comment: Are you using pandas? Pandas `apply` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @luanstat I've posted an answer below that doesn't need beautifulsoup and could clean up the column in two lines of code.  Hopefully it's an acceptable answer.  Let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked well for me in the past...

**Try:**

```
# first replace BR tags with spaces
df['clean_html_text'] = df['html_text'].str.replace(r'<br\s?/?>', ' ', regex=True)

# then remove all the other tags
df['clean_html_text'] = df['clean_html_text'].str.replace(r'<[^>]*>', '', regex=True)
```

**Output:**

```
      ID  name                                          html_text  \
0  12345  john  <p>this is a sentence</p><br /><u>the ball is ...   

                      clean_html_text  
0  this is a sentence the ball is red
```

---

If you did want to go via beautifulsoup, you would need a function to clean the string and run it using `.apply()`.  The bit below the `##########` is what you need.  It assumes the code you have in the question is correct and just needs applying to all the rows in the `html_text` column.

**Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html import unescape
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [12345], 'name': ['john'], 'html_text': ['<p>this is a sentence</p><br /><u>the ball is red</u></p>']})



###############



# function that takes a HTML string and return a the string with tags removed
def removeHTMLtags(x):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(x), 'lxml')
    return soup.get_text(separator=' ')

# for each row add the cleaned text (returned from the function) to a new column 'clean_html_text'
df['clean_html_text'] = df.apply(lambda x: removeHTMLtags(x['html_text']), axis=1)
```