# Print Email body using imap_tools in python

Tags: python, imap, imap-tools

I've been trying to print email body using python(using imap_tools lib)but it's not really working for me. here is the code snippet.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A, AND, OR, NOT
with MailBox('outlook.office365.com').login('test@test.com', 'test') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)):
        print(msg.text)
```

but when I print the subject using `msg.subject`, it's working fine. I tried using msg.html and here is the output.

```
<body lang="EN-IN" link="blue" vlink="#954F72" style="word-wrap:break-word"><div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal">Hi, this is a test email to store body in file<o:p></o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

note: this is not the whole HTML output, but this is to show that the email has some data in the body.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with that body?  It looks okay to me.

Comment: Not every message necessarily has both a .text and a .html body, the sender client can choose to include one, the other, or both.  Technically 'neither' is an option, but rarely seen in practice.

Comment: @Max It contains many HTML tags and other CSS components which I don't need. i am looking for a str which is the body

Comment: Then if the message doesn't already contain a text part, you'll need to remove them yourself.  There are several suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Comment: @Max the body is in text only, no HTML content is present in the body.

Comment: Obviously it is not text-only.  It may be very lightly styled HTML, but those are the normal tags you get from Outlook generated messages (“MsoNormal == microsoft office normal”).  It may not have images, but it _is_ HTML.  Either ask your sender to adjust their settings to actually text only, or strip them.